# SWIG & exceptions: avoid using throw(Exception) in C++

Tags: java, c++, swig

I am using SWIG to wrap a C++ library into a JAVA one following ideas from [Handling C++ exceptions in Java via SWIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993747/handling-c-exceptions-in-java-via-swig).

I have been able to wrap all my exceptions, however if a function launching an exception is not explicitly told in the C++ declaration, JAVA code does not work. Example:
if I do

```
class A {
    public:
         void f () throw (MyException){};
```

everything goes as expected. However, if I do

```
class A {
    public:
         void f (){};
```

When I catch the exception in JAVA using the proxy class

```
try {
     // this is the proxy wrapped (java) class
     A.f();
}
catch(MyException e)
{
    ...
}
```

JAVA compilation fails with the following error

```
exception MyExceptionn is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
```

I don't want to use exception notifications in my C++ code if I can avoid it http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm . Question is, can I avoid it? How?

Comment: Have you checked http://web.mit.edu/Ghudson/trac/src/swig-1.3.25/Doc/Manual/Java.html#exception_handling ? Apparently you have to catch the C++ exception and throw a Java one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make MyExtension extend RuntimeException rather than Exception, then it can be thrown from any function not just functions that explicitly declare a throws clause.

```
static class MyException extends RuntimeException {

}
```

...

```
static void f() {
    throw new MyException();
}
```

...

```
try {
    f();
} catch(MyException e) {

}
```